# Leaflet popup design not working properly on IE11

Tags: leaflet, javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I am using Leaflet on my map and I styled popup using Bootstrap 4. Design works good for all browsers expect IE11. Can someone help me to find the problem and fix it?

How popup looks in Firefox:

[image]

How popup looks in IE11

[image]

Link on site - http://www.rpbv.lv/uploads/Karte_v2/

Comment: This is rather strange. When I tried it at my job, I got the same result as you. When I tried it at home, it works OK in IE11. I'll try to find the reason tomorrow at my job.

Comment: This is even stranger. Now it works also at my job. I cannot reproduce strange behaviour any more. Can you try again? Maybe Bootstrap library was modified in the meantime.